# Configuring python for IIS

Tags: python, iis, flask

Following the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019 to configure flask app to run behind IIS and searching online I couldn't find a solution that fix my problem.

I have my web.config as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\envs\Scripts\python.exe"
                  arguments="-m flask run --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="C:\logs\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="FLASK_APP" value="app.py" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

A visit to the site just spit the following. I tried all possible solutions I came across which include giving IIS_IUSRS access. Running the app on command prompt runs just fine. The IIS error message is not helping.

[image]

**edit:**

after installing the http platformhandler and now on a different dev box, I can see the handler at work but just a different monster: 502.3 Bad Gateway

Detailed Error Information:

**Module**        httpPlatformHandler              **Requested URL**  http://127.0.0.1:5007/about

**Notification**  ExecuteRequestHandler         **Physical Path**  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\about

**Handler**       PythonHandler                 **Logon Method**   Anonymous

**Error Code**    0x8007042b                    **Logon User**     Anonymous

Which tells me the handler is just handling the url as just folders in my app root because `http://127.0.0.1:5007/about` is nothing but a route to:

myapp_about.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

myapp_about = Blueprint('about', __name__)


@myapp_about.route('/about')
def get_about():
    return jsonify({"wow": "We really are routed to here. maybe not"})
```

Comment: did you add a handler mapping for python and fast cgi in iis?https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I'm using HttpPlatform handler not FastCGI handler.

Comment: You may need to add requireAccess:
 <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I'll try that one but I'm now on a different box and made an edit to the question.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019, both using IIS 10.0. You must have the *HttpPlatformHandler* installed, as mentioned in the other answers. (Download it via Windows Platform Installer.)

The `<handlers>` section of my web.config is locked, so instead of editing the web.config directly, I used the *Add Module Mapping...* action on the IIS *Handler Mappings* GUI to add the Python handler:

[image: Image of Python handler]

You can also edit the website configuration directly via the IIS Manager's GUI:

[image: IIS Configuration Editor]

I use an absolute path for the FLASK_APP environment variable, but it seems to work without it too. (In fact, you can leave the environment variable out completely if you are using the default Flask app name of *app.py*.)

**web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Python37\python.exe"
                      arguments="-m flask run --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                      stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                      stdoutLogFile="C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\python.log"
                      startupTimeLimit="60"
                      processesPerApplication="16">
          <environmentVariables>
              <environmentVariable name="FLASK_APP" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hello.py" />
          </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works with the minimal Flask app below. (Maybe try this before adding *Blueprint* and different port numbers.)

**hello.py**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hi')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

[image: Image of browser output]

**Notes about Windows Security permissions:**

- It is **not** necessary for the Handler Mapping in IIS Manager to have **Execute** permissions checked. (**Script** permission is the default, and works as-is.)
- It is **not** necessary for IIS_IUSR to have **execute** permissions on *python.exe* or *flask.exe*.
- It is **not** necessary for IIS_IUSR to have **execute** permissions on *app.py* or *hello.py*.
- If logging is enabled, IIS_IUSR **must** have **write** permissions on the target folder (e.g. *C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles*) - not just on the *python.log* file, since it will likely add an additional suffix to the specified log file name.

Comment: @Murugan:
I got it working on Windows 10 too. Added some notes at the bottom with permissions to check. (The last point had me frustrated for a while!)

Comment: Could you please send any video tutorial?

Comment: @Dirco i've just added an entry in `hosts` file and everything seems to work fine. **BUT** i'm completely confused what's the difference between edinting **bindings** and editing **hosts** file ? even in official MS doc there's no mention for `hosts` file.

Comment: @Dirco tnx. it did work for me and it was so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anywhere in those instructions, but I think your problem is the HttpPlatformHandler.  Try removing that and see if you get a better/different error.   HttpPlatformHandler is not a default configuration element of IIS and need to be added, most likely by installing something like https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler.

Comment: installing the http platformhndler was one of the solution i came across and it didn't help. and removing the modules entry doesn't basically change the error.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't basically change the error"?   I built a brand new server, installed HttpPlatformHandler and slapped on your Web.config.  It fixed the configuration error and then choked on the fact that I don't have Python installed

Comment: Then I have no idea where I’m messing things up. I even tried to install the x86 of handler as well  but unfortunately my x64 windows 10 rejected it.

Comment: Did the error change at all thru any of your attempts?

Comment: Did a trial on a different box and made an update. I guess now I've uncovered a totally different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and worked doing below.
"Took a lot of effort but I got it to work a last

Must Install HttpPlatform https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler
Configuration Editor system.webServer/httpPlatform (Section is not locked)
Make sure app has permissions for log path stdoutLogFile="c:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
Had to setup up app.run(port=PORT) PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
Setup firewall to allow http-incoming requests"